# TypeError: Cannot read property 'nombre' of undefined

Tags: javascript

● Funciones › buscarAmigo › should return "{ nombre: "toni", edad: 33 }"

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nombre' of undefined

  78 |
  79 |     it('should return "{ nombre: "toni", edad: 33 }"', function() {
> 80 |       expect(buscarAmigo(amigos, 'toni').nombre).toBe('toni');
     |              ^
  81 |     });
  82 |     it('should return "{ nombre: "toni", edad: 33 }"', function() {
  83 |       expect(buscarAmigo(amigos, 'Emi').nombre).toBe('Emi');

  at Object.<anonymous> (tests/checkpoint.test.js:80:14)
```

Comment: var amigos =  [{ nombre: 'toni', edad: 33 } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }];

 var toni = amigos.find (item =>{
  return item.nombre = "toni"
 })

console.log(toni)

 }

Comment: Ponte en el pellejo de alguien que no eres tú, y no tiene ni idea del código con el que estás trabajando... Entenderías lo que hay aquí expuesto? Porque veo un trocito enano de código con una línea marcada con el error, pero no veo la función que da problemas en ningún lado, y luego veo un comentario con código ilegible que tampoco me ayuda, y si tú no te has molestado en pasar 5min editando la pregunta para que sea legible, por qué ha de perder nadie 10 minutos en ayudarte con el problema?? Lo que quiero decir es, **pon todo el código relacionado con el problema** y **expresalo claramente**

Comment: function buscarAmigo(amigos, nombre) {
  // La funcion llamada 'buscarAmigo' recibe como argumento un array llamado 'amigos' que contiene
  // en cada posición del arreglo un objeto que tiene como propiedades 'nombre' y 'edad'. También
  // recibe un string llamado 'nombre'.
  // Debe devolver el objeto cuya propiedad 'nombre' coincida con el string 'nombre' recibido por argumento.
  // Ej:
  //  var amigos = [{ nombre: 'toni', edad: 33 } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }];
  //  buscarAmigo(amigos, 'toni') debe devolver { nombre: 'toni', edad: 33 };

  // Tu código aca:

Comment: eso tengo que realizar

Comment: @LucasChiofalo, por favor no uses el área de comentarios para añadir código de tu pregunta. Edita tu pregunta haciendo clic en [edit] y agrega el código allí. De lo contrario está difícil que te podamos ayudar. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

No está del todo bien formulada la pregunta me parece. De hecho, no hiciste ninguna, es difícil para quienes traten de ayudar entender cual es tu problema. Ten esto en cuenta para cuando agregues nuevas preguntas en el sitio. En cuanto a tu problema, creo que la expresion lambda de la funcion find está mal resulta. Estas usando "=" cuando en realidad necesitas hacer una comparación "=="

amigos.find(item => item.nombre == 'toni')

Comment: function buscarAmigo(amigos, nombre) { // La funcion llamada 'buscarAmigo' recibe como argumento un array llamado 'amigos' que contiene
  // en cada posición del arreglo un objeto que tiene como propiedades 'nombre' y 'edad'. También
  // recibe un string llamado 'nombre'.
  // Debe devolver el objeto cuya propiedad 'nombre' coincida con el string 'nombre' recibido por argumento.
  // Ej: //  var amigos = [{ nombre: 'toni', edad: 33 } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }];
  //  buscarAmigo(amigos, 'toni') debe devolver { nombre: 'toni', edad: 33 }; // Tu código aca:

Comment: @LucasChiofalo, por favor no uses el área de comentarios para añadir código de tu pregunta. Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código allí. Por favor leer [ask] y [mcve].